# Expense approval workflow + hierarchy approval

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, workflow, google-forms

I'm working to expand on the workflow script posted here:

[James Ferreira Workflow video.](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/emailapprovalusinggooglescriptandaform)

---

```
function sendEmail(e) {

var email = e.values[1];
var Item = e.values[2];
var cost = e.values[3];
var vendor = e.values[4]; 

var url = '<SPREADSHEET>';

  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'&reply='+email; 
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'&reply='+email;

  var html = "<body>"+
                "<h3>Please review</h3><br />"+
                  Item +": " + cost+ ": " + vendor+ "<br />"+ 
                "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
                "<a href="+ reject +">Reject</a><br />"+
             "</body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail("<MY EMIAL>", "Approval Request", 
                    "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});  
}


function doGet(e){

  var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Buy it!' : 'Not this time, Keep saving'; 

  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Purchase Request", 
                    "Your manager said: "+ answer);   

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('<h3>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + ' saying: '+ answer + '</h3>'))
  return app
}
```

**Question 1)** How do you build in an additional approval flow dependent on the cost?
**Question 2)** Depending on the approval amount how can I adjust the manager emaill?

For example: if the cost is above £500 I would like to send the approval email to another email account / manager. Would be amazing if the script could automatically recognise this.

Any support of this is much appreciated,
Andrew